# Different intrinsic parameters for stereo camera

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, camera-calibration

I am fairly new to computer vision and OpenCV so my details might no be throughout, sorry.

I am currently trying to calibrate my stereo camera to get both intrinsic and extrinsic parameters. My end goal is to undistort and rectify the images pair and use correspondence to find certain points in each images.

The stereo camera I am using: http://www.webcamerausb.com/elp-synchronized-dual-lens-stereo-usb-camera-13mp-hd-960p-webcam-3d-vr-web-camera-module-with-13-cmos-ov9715-image-sensor-camera-module-mini-industrial-usb20-web-cam-plugplay-for-androidlinuxwindows-p-285.html

Images taken: 20 pairs of stereo images

This is the snippet of code I am using for camera calibration:

```
for fname in images:
        img = cv2.imread(fname)
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray, (width, height), None)

        if ret:
            print(fname)
            objpoints.append(objp)

            corners2 = cv2.cornerSubPix(gray, corners, (11, 11), (-1, -1), criteria)
            imgpoints.append(corners2)

            img = cv2.drawChessboardCorners(img, (width, height), corners2, ret)

ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.calibrateCamera(objpoints, imgpoints, gray.shape[::-1], None, None)
```

I calibrated the left lens and right lens separately. However my issue is that the focal length in the camera matrix for each of the lens are different.

LEFT LENS:

```
K: !!opencv-matrix
   rows: 3
   cols: 3
   dt: d
   data: [ 2.7630975322098088e+03, 0., 6.3154856415725897e+02, 0.,
       2.8097306962970929e+03, 4.9132766901283384e+02, 0., 0., 1. ]
D: !!opencv-matrix
   rows: 1
   cols: 5
   dt: d
   data: [ -4.6255313067932485e-01, -5.5060376742654917e+01,
       -9.9065660338455458e-02, 4.4853567872048555e-02,
       8.3136561769726973e+02 ]
```

RIGHT LENS:

```
K: !!opencv-matrix
   rows: 3
   cols: 3
   dt: d
   data: [ 1.1603188984395067e+03, 0., 6.4378728024327643e+02, 0.,
       1.1556999845227924e+03, 5.0433004252302896e+02, 0., 0., 1. ]
D: !!opencv-matrix
   rows: 1
   cols: 5
   dt: d
   data: [ -6.0796521210889765e-01, 6.0622199106747054e-01,
       -1.4097123552960564e-02, 1.4581825861357409e-02,
       -6.8179582332173561e-01 ]
```

What am I doing wrong and how should I correct the issues?

Thanks!

What I have tried:
Calibrated camera individually
Calibrate both camera at once

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are calibrating monocular cameras only. Your current code is not computing the relative pose of one camera with respect to the other. To achieve this part, you can have a look at the function 'cv.stereoCalibrate'

https://docs.opencv.org/4.6.0/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga91018d80e2a93ade37539f01e6f07de5

Solving the problem of monocular calibration first will make sure you have good input data to be used for the next stage of stereo calibration.

I do not see anything fundamentally wrong with your code sample. With the entire code, and some sample input images, it would be easier to find the origin of the problem.

[CalibPro](https://calibpro.com) provides an easy to use interface to calibrate cameras without writing a single line of code. I would definitely recommend using it to see if you obtain the same results.

[Disclaimer] I am the founder of Calibpro. I am happy to help you to use the platform and I'd love to have your feedback.